# How to change default dialer app in Asus Zenfone 5?

Tags: phone-app, asus-zenfone-5

How can I change the default dialer app in Asus zenfone 5. I tried Settings → Apps → All, then selecting the phone app. There was a Clear defaults button which was greyed out.

Do I have to get root access to change it?

The purpose of it is to automate a conference call using uiautomator and adb shell. For this reason we are supposed to have a same UI for all devices so that we can automate it easily.

But right now, even when I call with Truedialer I get this default screen that I used earlier. The resourceid is *com.asus.asusincallui:id/holdButton*.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Comment: You need at least another dialer app to change it to. Your question didn't mention that part: do you have another dialer installed, and if so which?

Comment: I have installed True dialer.

Comment: OK, that's a start. Now what happens if you e.g. click a phone number in a text message (or perform some other action that should invoke the dialer – appart from starting it directly via its icon)? That should now ask you which of the two to use, and whether only once or *always* – the latter making it the "default dialer".

Comment: Yes I know the process. The problem is much broader. Can I email you ??

Comment: No, sorry. But you can [edit] your question and closer describe your issue. There are others around here who might "chime in" with ideas I wouldn't think of, so it's much better to solve the issue here (if it's possible to solve, that is).

Comment: It is called incallui.  [what is android incallui?](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/138306)