# What is Android InCallUI?

Tags: terminology

What is Android InCallUI? I keep seeing it under apps I've used.

I googled it and I keep seeing it related to this xPrivacy Pro software. I have an Android ZTE Z812 phone and am wondering how I find out if this software is installed on my phone and how to access it?

Comment: Include links to what you found and post a screenshot please!

Answer (score 7):

[InCallUI](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/InCallUI/) = In Call User Interface.  It handles the display when you're in a call; it has nothing to do with privacy software and you can't uninstall it since it is a core system app.

Comment: Ok thank u. How do I know if privacy is installed on my phone?

Comment: Look in the list in Settings -> Applications.

Comment: Applications cannot install themselves in Android, not without your express permission, due to the very nature of how Android is built and it's built in security system. If you have not turned on Unknown Sources in Settings-Security, the chances of something being installed without your knowledge are near zero, assuming your device has not been out of your control for an extended period of time.